# Symbols undefined in NASM for a label defined in one file, used in another

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I want to read numbers from the keyboard, and the reading function should be a module in a different file. However I get errors telling me the variables I want to use are not defined.

How can I fix this problem? The main program is here

```
bits 32

global start        
extern exit
import exit msvcrt.dll 


%include "lab11p1citire.asm"
%include "lab11p1minim.asm"
%include "lab11p1afisare.asm"

segment data use32 class=data
    format db "%u", 0
    nume_fisier db "min.txt", 0
    mod_acces db "w", 0
    text db "Numarul minim din sirul citit scris in baza 16 este: %x", 0
    descriptor dd 0 
    numere dd 0
    


segment code use32 class=code
    start:
        call citire
        
        call minim
         
        call afisare
        
        push    dword 0      ; push the parameter for exit onto the stack
        call    [exit]       ; call exit to terminate the program
```

and the reading module, located in the lab11p1citire.asm file is here

```
%ifndef _LAB11P1CITIRE_ASM_
%define _LAB11P1CITIRE_ASM_

extern scanf
import scanf msvcrt.dll

    citire:
        mov edi, 1
                repeta:
                    push dword numere
                    push dword format
                    call [scanf]
                    add esp, 4*2
                                        
                    mov ebx, [numere]
                    cmp ebx, 0
                    je afara
                                
                    mov eax, [numere]
                    mov [numere+4*edi], eax
                    inc edi
                    jmp repeta
                afara:
     
         ret
%endif
```

Errors:

```
lab11p1citire.asm:11: error: symbol `numere' undefined
lab11p1citire.asm:12: error: symbol `format' undefined
lab11p1citire.asm:16: error: symbol `numere' undefined
lab11p1citire.asm:21: error: symbol `numere' undefined
```

I tried a lot of thigs to include the numere and format from the data segment to the new module, but they simply do not work or they mess up the main, because the compiler tells me the numere and format variables are redefined.

Comment: There's no `extern numere` in the file that uses it without defining it itself.  Exactly like with `extern scanf` to tell NASM about that symbol which is defined outside this file, which you'll supply at link time.  You'll need `global numere` and `global format` to export them from the file that defines them.